# "Error initializing" frei0r filter even though it is enabled

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I just installed `ffmpeg` with the `frei0r` library from [gyan.dev](http://gyan.dev) but I don't seem to be able to use it for some reason (this is on Windows).

When using this exact command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v frei0r=pixeliz0r=0.02:0.02 output.mp4
```

I get this error:

```
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 000001ecbb32c240] Option 'pixeliz0r' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001ecba7e3a40] Error initializing filter 'frei0r' with args 'pixeliz0r=0.02:0.02'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

`frei0r` is enabled:

```
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
```

So why is this error happening? I also tried using `glow`, and got the same error. Other libraries work fine and I have tried reinstalling.

Comment: How about ```-vf "frei0r=pixeliz0r:0.02|0.02"``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old syntax has changed. Use:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "frei0r=filter_name=pixeliz0r:filter_params=0.02|0.02" output
```

See [FFmpeg frei0r filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#frei0r-1).